# Removing teak oil from varnished wood

Tags: wooden-furniture

Someone "polished" my varnished mahogany dining table with teak oil.  How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If the table was varnished, then the applied oil will not have penetrated and could be removed with a rag soaked in mineral spirits. Don't use more volatile solvents as they could soften or damage your varnish. Afterwards, wipe clean with a separate damp cloth to remove all traces of the oil and spirits.